# how to pass a variable from .sh script to qmake?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I'm trying to build a qt project which will use boost binary libraries. And I want path to libs to be passed from .sh script to qmake and extended in .pro file.
So I have this .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

message("Master pro file path : ["$$[BOOST_LIBS_PATH]"]")

LIBS += -L$$[BOOST_LIBS_PATH]
```

and a script file that run qmake:

```
BOOST_LIBS_PATH=/path/to/boost

echo $BOOST_LIBS_PATH

qmake-qt4 qt_test_proj.pro -r -spec linux-g++
```

but at the complie output I receive

```
Project MESSAGE: boost libs path : []
```

so `BOOST_LIBS_PATH` in `.pro` file is still empty.

Comment: if it's as the make command, then `qmake-qt4 qt_test_proj.pro -r -spec linux-g++ BOOST_LIBS_PATH=/path/to/boost` should work.

Comment: what if you replace the `$$[]` with `$${}`

Comment: that worked! I changed `qmake-qt4 qt_test_proj.pro -r -spec linux-g++ BOOST_LIBS_PATH=/path/to/boost` in script and `$$[]` to `$${}` in .pro file.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can pass the path with an environment variable, but you do not set any. I would do it in the following way.

In the script file

```
export BOOST_LIBS_PATH="/path/to/boost"
echo $BOOST_LIBS_PATH
```

Qt docs say that

> To obtain the contents of an environment value at the time when the generated Makefile is processed, use the $(...) operator.

So in the project file

```
# Note the usage of $() operator.
message("Master pro file path : ["$(BOOST_LIBS_PATH)"]")
[..]
LIBS += -L$(BOOST_LIBS_PATH])
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, that's been useful!